# Geographic locations where lock screen photos in Windows 11 were shot

Tags: windows-11, lock-screen

Some of the photos in Windows 11 lock screen are so beautiful that I would like to travel to these places once in my lifetime.

However, I can't find the locations where these photos were taken. In the lock screen itself there are no hints either. I don't see a link named "Like what you see" in the lock screen, as some people suggest they have.

Anyone has a clue how to find these places? Thank you.

Comment: Does [Find the Actual Location Where a Spotlight (Lock Screen) Image was Shot » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/location-where-a-spotlight-image-shot/) answer your question?

Comment: Start - Settings - search for "Lock Screen", then choose "Lock Screen Settings". Then, next to Personalize your Lock Screen, choose Windows Spotlight instead of Picture or Slideshow. Win11 will show more info on the lockscreen.

Comment: @DavidPostill I was able to find the today's lock screen image only (using google image search). The question still exists for other (older) lock screen images, it would be convenient to see a gallery with all images and their locations. The Assets folder does not store previous images.

Comment: @Gantendo I already have Windows Spotlight selected there, but I don't see anything except datetime, wifi and battery settings in the lockscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that no info about the picture is displayed on the lock screen when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is required to sign in to Windows. In this case, I didn't find a way to find out the location. You may look into the properties of Spotlight files, sometimes the photos contain description, location.

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is *not* required, there are interactive elements on the lock screen, and the top right corner has *Like what you see* which expands on mouse hover and shows the details about the image location. Clicking it usually open Bing in Microsoft Edge with the search for the location.